# Simple recursion returns null in PHP

Tags: php, recursion, null, return

Where am I wrong?

The code looks OK, but the function returns NULL.

```
$ar = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
$n = 6;

$new_n = chckn($n, $ar);

echo $new_n;

function chckn($n, $ar) {
    if(!in_array($n, $ar)) {
        echo "===$n===\n";
        return $n;
    } else {
        $n = rand(1, 10);
        chckn($n, $ar);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ar = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
$n = 6;

$new_n = chckn($n, $ar);

echo $new_n;

function chckn($n, $ar){
    if(!in_array($n, $ar)){
        //echo "===$n===\n";
        return $n;
    } else {
        $n = rand(1,10);
        return chckn($n, $ar);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Himanshu Patel! I have missed a return in the recursion.

Comment: Yes, you might want to add an explanation instead of just dumping code.